# Nested Array with one foreach Loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I need to have access to a array which looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [54] => Array
            (
                [test] => 54
                [tester] => result
            )
         )
)

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
  echo $key;// prints 0
  echo $value;// prints Array
  /*
   now i can iterate through $value but i dont want it solve that way example:
  foreach($value as $k=>$v)
  {
    echo $k;//prints test
    echo $v; //prints 54
  }
  */

}
```

How can iterate just once ? to get the values of **test** and **tester**? 
I hope i could explain my problem clear

Comment: Does the array have only one array (which contains more arrays) or does it have many arrays which contain many arrays? You need to give a slightly better example for your test array.

Comment: And do you allow other functions like array_map etc...?

Comment: @zaf its a array which contains many arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SPL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)'s [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator($array), 
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $key => $val) {
    if($key === 'test' || $key === 'tester') {
        echo "$key = $val \n";
    }
}
```

This will find all array elements with a value of either *test* or *tester*, regardless of where it appears in the multidimensional array. If you have to narrow it to a specific depth in the array, you can match against `$iterator->getDepth()`.

---

You can also put the if condition into the method body of a [FilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php)'s [accept()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filteriterator.accept.php) method, e.g.

```
class TestFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        return ($this->key() === 'test' || $this->key() === 'tester');
    }
}
```

and then wrap the iterator in it before `foreach`ing it, e.g.

```
$iterator = new TestFilter($iterator); // wrap iterator from first example
foreach($iterator as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val \n";    
}
```

Further reading:

- [Introduction to SPL](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, if my interpretation of the question is correct in that you just want to get the deepest (i.e. non-array) items from the array then life could be made somewhat simpler by using `new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array))` and not having any condition within the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @salathe granted, if you take the OP's example literally, then the default LEAVES_ONLY would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous function to list the items. This will use recursion every time an array is encountered as an element:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, create_function('$item, $key', 
    'echo "$key => $item<br />";'
));
```

Or when using PHP 5.3:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) { 
    echo "$key => $item<br />";
});
```

This will be faster (and more readable) than create_function(). However this construct is only available in PHP 5.3 and up.

Both will output:

```
test => 54
tester => result
```

Which is exactly what you want, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This would only work for this specific array:

```
foreach($array[0][54] as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key;// prints test and tester
    echo $value;// prints 54 and result
}
```

Comment: Noop thats not what i need it should also woth for [120][2] and soon

Comment: This answer shouldn't have been voted down, fair enough it's way too specific, but the question didn't really provide much in the way of a proper array structure, just a very basic example.